# Fast loading of png files

Tags: performance-tuning, import, image, png-format

I need to process through 600 images that are stored as png-files. Each file has 8.3-ish Mb and 2400x2400 pixel (Real32). For a single processor it takes 0.93sec per image to be loaded with Import (Dell Latitude E6430, i7, windows 7, 64Bit). The processing takes 0.617sec. The processing is subject to optimization and should become even faster. So the bottle neck is the image loading. I want to increase speed as in future we will need to process 2000 images per run. Using a dual core maschine and ParallelTable I can increase speed by a factor of 1.23. Then going through the images takes ~15min. Also directly loading the png data with Import["... .png",{"Data"}] is not faster.

Is there a way to speed up reading/loading of png images? Can the loading of images be better distributed on the cores?

Comment: You could try using `ImageFileFilter` and related commands to bypass the need to read the images into RAM.

Comment: I found out that somehow mathematica is relatively slow in reading files (e.g compared to IDL). I have a similar problem described here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104626/finding-mean-brightness-standard-deviation-count-of-pixels-in-gray-scale-image

Comment: Is it possible to import other language into Mathematica to get it done faster? I had a look at C (C++) but so far have not succeed to find something useful. I do not now about IDL though.

Comment: The Import/Export framework is pretty large because it needs to check for all kinds of possibilities. You can distill it down to a call of the function ``Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG["tmp/test.png"]``, but even that does only speed it up a small amount. I'm not sure you can make it really fast without writing external code that calls a fast library. Can you provide your exact system and a sample "PNG"?

Comment: You may not want the image data in `Real32`. That's what you get from the default `ImageData[image]`. The original image data, with integer pixel values, can be had with `ImageData[image, Automatic]`. That might be faster to work with, depending on what you're doing.

Comment: Did you play around with the graining option of the `Parallelxxx` functions? As each import takes quite long, you might get more speedup by choosing `Method->FinestGrained` (depending on how clever the system chooses the partitioning automatically).

Comment: My i7 laptop behaves completely different to my Dell T550 office pc. This one has 8 cores which run on 98% load (HDD no SSD) when running the code. The laptop not even runs at 100% with two cores. The suggestion by halirutan gives some improvement. That results in 3 min. calculation time for 600 images. The grid I have with another T5500 does improve by 15%-ish. I would need a faster HDD and or LAN to make it work faster.

Comment: Take a look at [ReadPNG](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ReadPNG). From its description: "bypasses most of the functionality of the Import, making it less flexible and more limited, but significantly faster. It should be used judiciously when performance is critical."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be faster (you will need to install [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html)):

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]

loadpng$source="
// Load a PNG image from a file into memory.
// Placed into the public domain by Mark Adler, January 24, 2016

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <png.h>            // libpng

// Image returned by image_load().  For samples, Y means grey scale, RGB is
// red-green-blue, and A is an alpha channel.  The samples in each pixel are in
// the listed order in the row (e.g. RGBRGBRGB...).  Each of rows[0..height-1]
// and the rows vector itself are allocated.  image_free() should be used to
// release the allocated memory.  For one-byte samples, the samples are
// accessed using rows.b.  For two-byte samples, the samples are accessed using
// rows.w (the samples will have the correct endianess).  The original image
// may have been palettized, had less than 8-bits per pixel, and/or had a tRNS
// transparent pixel value, all of which are expanded for the returned image.
// The pre-expansion image bit depth and color type are saved in depth and
// type.
typedef struct {
    uint32_t width;             // image width in pixels (not zero)
    uint32_t height;            // image height in pixels (not zero)
    uint16_t depth;             // original (pre-expansion) bit depth
    uint16_t type;              // original (pre-expansion) color type
    uint16_t samples;           // 1 = Y, 2 = YA, 3 = RGB, 4 = RGBA
    uint16_t bytes;             // bytes per sample = 1 or 2
    size_t row_size;            // bytes per row = width * samples * bytes
    union {
        unsigned char **b;      // array of height rows, each row_size long
        uint16_t **w;           // same array for when bytes == 2
    } rows;
} image_t;

// Avoid writing a warning message to stderr -- passed to create function.
static void no_warn(png_structp png, const char *msg) {
    (void)png;
    (void)msg;
}

// Avoid writing an error message to stderr -- passed to create function.
static void no_errmsg(png_structp png, const char *msg) {
    (void)msg;
    longjmp(png_jmpbuf(png), 1);        // 1 = libpng error
}

// Free the allocations used by image.
static void image_free(image_t *image) {
    if (image->rows.b == NULL)
        return;
    for (size_t n = image->height; n;)
        free(image->rows.b[--n]);
    free(image->rows.b);
    image->rows.b = NULL;
}

// Load the PNG image from path, returning the result in image.  The return
// value is 0 on success, -1 if there is a memory allocation error, 1 if the
// input is invalid, or 2 if path could not be opened.
static int image_load(const char *path, image_t *image) {
    // create libpng read structure
    png_structp png = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING,
                                             NULL, no_errmsg, no_warn);
    if (png == NULL)
        return -1;

    // set up error handling
    FILE * volatile fp = NULL;
    image->rows.b = NULL;
    png_infop info = NULL;
    {
        int jmp = setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png));
        if (jmp) {                      // someone longjmp'ed here
            image_free(image);
            png_destroy_read_struct(&png, &info, NULL);
            if (fp != NULL)
                fclose(fp);
            return jmp;
        }
    }

    // create libpng image information structure
    info = png_create_info_struct(png);
    if (info == NULL)
        longjmp(png_jmpbuf(png), -1);

    // open input file
    fp = fopen(path, \"rb\");
    if (fp == NULL)
        longjmp(png_jmpbuf(png), 2);
    png_init_io(png, fp);

    // read png header with the image information, save header data
    png_read_info(png, info);
    image->width = png_get_image_width(png, info);
    image->height = png_get_image_height(png, info);
    image->depth = png_get_bit_depth(png, info);
    image->type = png_get_color_type(png, info);

    // expand palettes, expand samples to 8 or 16 bits, and expand tRNS to an
    // alpha channel if present -- save the expanded image information for how
    // the image will be returned
    png_set_expand(png);
    png_read_update_info(png, info);
    {
        unsigned type = png_get_color_type(png, info);
        image->samples = (type >> 2) + (type & 2) + 1;
    }
    image->bytes = png_get_bit_depth(png, info) >> 3;
    image->row_size = png_get_rowbytes(png, info);

    // allocate space for the png image (use calloc() to initialize as NULLs)
    image->rows.b = calloc(image->height, sizeof(unsigned char *));
    if (image->rows.b == NULL)
        longjmp(png_jmpbuf(png), -1);
    for (size_t n = 0; n < image->height; n++)
        if ((image->rows.b[n] = malloc(image->row_size)) == NULL)
            longjmp(png_jmpbuf(png), -1);

    // match the endianess of 16-bit samples to this machine
    if (image->bytes == 2) {
        const unsigned little = 1;
        if (*(const unsigned char *)&little)
            png_set_swap(png);
    }

    // read in the png image and return success (if no longjmp's)
    png_read_image(png, image->rows.b);
    png_read_end(png, info);
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png, &info, NULL);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

#include \"mathlink.h\"
#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion( ) {
   return WolframLibraryVersion;
}

DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData) {
   return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( ) {
   return;
}

static void report(WolframLibraryData libData, const char *name,
                   const char *err, const char *text) {
   MLINK link = libData->getMathLink(libData);
      /* name::err = \"`1`\" */
   MLPutFunction(link, \"EvaluatePacket\", 1);
   MLPutFunction(link, \"Set\", 2);
   MLPutFunction(link, \"MessageName\", 2);
   MLPutSymbol(link, name);
   MLPutString(link, err);
   MLPutString(link, \"`1`\");
   libData->processMathLink(link);
   if (MLNextPacket(link) == RETURNPKT)
      MLNewPacket(link);
      /* Message[name::err, text] */
   MLPutFunction(link, \"EvaluatePacket\", 1);
   MLPutFunction(link, \"Message\", 2);
   MLPutFunction(link, \"MessageName\", 2);
   MLPutSymbol(link, name);
   MLPutString(link, err);
   MLPutString(link, text);
   libData->processMathLink(link);
   if (MLNextPacket(link) == RETURNPKT)
       MLNewPacket(link);
}

DLLEXPORT mint loadpng(WolframLibraryData libData, MLINK link) {
   const char *path;
   int len;
   const char *errmsg[] = {
      \"Out of memory\",                           /* -1 */
      \"Unexpected return code\",                  /* < -1 or > 2 */
      \"Invalid PNG input\",                       /* 1 */
      \"Could not open file\"                      /* 2 */
   };

   if (MLTestHead(link, \"List\", &len) && len == 1 &&
       MLGetType(link) == MLTKSTR && MLGetString(link, &path)) {
      MLNewPacket(link);
      image_t image;
      int ret = image_load(path, &image);
      MLReleaseString(link, path);
      int *a;
      if (ret == 0 && (ret = -1,
           (a = malloc(((sizeof(int) * image.height) * image.width) *
                      image.samples)) != NULL)) {
         size_t n = 0;
         for (size_t i = 0; i < image.height; i++) {
             size_t m = 0;
             for (size_t j = 0; j < image.width; j++)
                 for (size_t k = 0; k < image.samples; k++)
                     a[n++] = image.bytes == 1 ? image.rows.b[i][m++] :
                                                 image.rows.w[i][m++];
         }
         image_free(&image);
         const int dims[3] = {image.height, image.width, image.samples};
         MLPutFunction(link, \"Image\", 3);
         MLPutInteger32Array(link, a, dims, NULL, 3);
         free(a);
         MLPutString(link,
                     image.type == 0 && image.depth == 1 ? \"Bit\" :
                     image.bytes == 1 ? \"Byte\" : \"Bit16\");
         MLPutFunction(link, \"Rule\", 2);
         MLPutSymbol(link, \"ColorSpace\");
         MLPutString(link,
                     image.type == 0 && image.depth == 1 ? \"Automatic\" :
                     image.samples < 3 ? \"Grayscale\" : \"RGB\");
      }
      else {
         MLPutSymbol(link, \"Null\");
         report(libData, \"loadpng\",
                ret < 0 ? \"memerr\" : \"invalid\",
                errmsg[ret < -1 || ret > 2 ? 1 : ret + 1]);
      }
   }
   else {
      MLClearError(link);
      MLNewPacket(link);
      MLPutSymbol(link, \"Null\");
      report(libData, \"loadpng\", \"arg\",
             \"String expected at position 1 as the only argument\");
   }
   MLClearError(link);
   return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}";

If[Head[lib]===String,LibraryUnload[lib]]
lib=CreateLibrary[loadpng$source,"loadpng","CompileOptions"->"-lpng",
  "ShellOutputFunction"->Print]
loadpng=LibraryFunctionLoad[lib,"loadpng",LinkObject,LinkObject]
```

Then you can:

```
loadpng["myimage.png"]
```

which will return the same image as:

```
Import["myimage.png"]
```

Comment: That is well prepared code. I just did not managed to get libpng installed properly. I need to dig into that further. It is not so straight forward to implement it into MS visual studio 2010 as initially expected. Once I have it running I will report.

Comment: I get the error: cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-lpng'
loadpng.c
C:\Users\gbj\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-goe-nb-0422-8072-6136-1\loadpng.c(53) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type' ---and plenty more of those. Can you help please?

Comment: Sorry, no, I can't help with compiling in your Windows environment as I am thankfully unfamiliar. You might try to first get compiling C code to work without trying to use libpng. You will then need to figure out the compiler options to use other libraries, like libpng.

Comment: What is -lpng for?

Comment: In typical Unix compilation/linking options, `-lxxx` will link in the library `libxxx` with whatever the standard extension is on that system (e.g. `.so`, `.dylib`), assuming that it is in the library search path. So `-lpng` links in the `libpng` library. I don't know what the comparable option would be on your system.

Comment: Thank you! I get the now error: error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'row_size' Is this related to libpng?

Comment: That is in line 32.

Comment: I'd guess not. All I can say is that the code is written in standard, portable C. You're on your own. Good luck.

Comment: Can you post the pure c code (not a changed version as Mathematica string). I think the lines are messed up due to \ signs.

Comment: Sigh. No. The backslashes are how you put double quotes inside a double-quoted string in Mathematica.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35407/discussion-between-eisbar-and-mark-adler).

Comment: **Final comment**: I do not get this code runing under windows (MM 10.3, MSVS 2010, zlib1.2.8, lpng1.6.3). I get many errors.like  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type' in row 53 that is `for (size_t n = image->height; n;)`

Comment: After a little digging, I found that Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 does not support the C99 (1999) standard, and it appears that they have no intent to fully support it even today! In other words, Microsoft does not support the C standard that is now 17 years old (the same age as my younger son). Not much I can do about that. Every other currently maintained C compiler that I am aware of fully supports C99. You can instead use Intel C or GNU C (gcc) on Windows, both of which, of course, fully support C99. You might try MSVS 2015 to see how much it supports, but it probably won't work either.

Comment: By the way, the C99 thing there is the declaration of a variable in the for statement, local to the for loop. You can try to pull those declarations out. E.g. `size_t n; for (n = image->height; n;)`, and then see what other C99 thing will cause a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up and digging into it. I am currently have a closer look to it and I want to install an according complier under windows.